# The size of user profile image in this forum is smaller than in other forums, why?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-profile

The size of user profile image in this forum (programmers.stackexchange.com) is smaller than in other forums (*.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow.com), why?

[image]

In programmers.stackexchange.com, the size of image, frame, and padding is not aesthetically beautiful. It is just my opinion that maybe incorrect. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the design (assuming you mean the picture on [this page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/47/chrisf) - as an example).

Comment: +1 By design. I understood now. :)

Comment: I think the size of the frame, padding and image is not proportional. I don't know whether other users feel the same.

Comment: to add what @chrisF answered already, I made the the gravatar smaller because unlike the other SE sites, this site's user picture has a sticky note "frame." As for the padding, I have adjusted the CSS bit to make the sticky note more square, and the padding more even. It will be in the next build.

Comment: @Jin: Thanks. It is much better now.

Answer (score 2):

We use http://gravatar.com for avatars.

The native size of the avatar is 128x128 as you can see on individual user pages -- this is also the maximum that Gravatar supports. I think this is quite large and I'm not sure why you would feel otherwise.

edit: as the OP said, for some reason Jin (our designer) decided to resize the avatar on the user page for this particular site. I will let him comment on that.

Comment: Please kindly see my update. The image size in tex.stackexchange.com is bigger than in programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @xport oh, I see -- that makes more sense, thank you!

Comment: Actually Gravatar supports up to 512 I think. See http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/55db06ceffe066c53bf7121fb3e23eea?s=512&d=identicon&r=PG

Comment: @josh interesting, the last time I checked was in 2008 -- maybe they've increased it. 128x128 seems.. sufficient.. though :)

Comment: Yep, more then enough.